# Unable to build ffmpeg for ExoPlayer

Tags: android, ffmpeg, exoplayer

I'm trying to add support for multiple audio formats in my app but cannot seem to build the ffmpeg extension on my mac.

I followed this readme:https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/dev-v2/extensions/ffmpeg

But I keep getting this error:

```
</Users/mac/NDKK>/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi16-clang is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "ffbuild/config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.
```

I tried NDK20 as well as NDK19 but the same error, so need help from someone who is familiar with this.

I'm trying to build the following formats "aac ac3 eac3 dca".

Edit: Here's the full commands and logs:

```
apples-iMac:~ mac$ cd Exoplayer
apples-iMac:Exoplayer mac$ EXOPLAYER_ROOT="$(pwd)"
apples-iMac:Exoplayer mac$ FFMPEG_EXT_PATH="${EXOPLAYER_ROOT}/extensions/ffmpeg/src/main"
apples-iMac:Exoplayer mac$ NDK_PATH="</Users/mac/NDKK>"
apples-iMac:Exoplayer mac$ HOST_PLATFORM="darwin-x86_64"
apples-iMac:Exoplayer mac$ ENABLED_DECODERS=(aac ac3 eac3 dca)
apples-iMac:Exoplayer mac$ cd "${FFMPEG_EXT_PATH}/jni" && \
> ln -s "$FFMPEG_PATH" ffmpeg
ln: ffmpeg/.: File exists
apples-iMac:jni mac$ cd "${FFMPEG_EXT_PATH}/jni" && \
> ./build_ffmpeg.sh \
>   "${FFMPEG_EXT_PATH}" "${NDK_PATH}" "${HOST_PLATFORM}" "${ENABLED_DECODERS[@]}"
</Users/mac/NDKK>/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi16-clang is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "ffbuild/config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.
Makefile:2: ffbuild/config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:40: /tools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:41: /ffbuild/common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /ffbuild/library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:96: /fftools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:97: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:98: /doc/examples/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:163: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
Makefile:2: ffbuild/config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:40: /tools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:41: /ffbuild/common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /ffbuild/library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:96: /fftools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:97: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:98: /doc/examples/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:163: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
Makefile:2: ffbuild/config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:40: /tools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:41: /ffbuild/common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /ffbuild/library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:96: /fftools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:97: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:98: /doc/examples/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:163: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
</Users/mac/NDKK>/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android21-clang is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "ffbuild/config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.
Makefile:2: ffbuild/config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:40: /tools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:41: /ffbuild/common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /ffbuild/library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:96: /fftools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:97: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:98: /doc/examples/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:163: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
Makefile:2: ffbuild/config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:40: /tools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:41: /ffbuild/common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /ffbuild/library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:96: /fftools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:97: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:98: /doc/examples/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:163: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
Makefile:2: ffbuild/config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:40: /tools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:41: /ffbuild/common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /ffbuild/library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:96: /fftools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:97: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:98: /doc/examples/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:163: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
</Users/mac/NDKK>/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/i686-linux-android16-clang is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "ffbuild/config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.
Makefile:2: ffbuild/config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:40: /tools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:41: /ffbuild/common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /ffbuild/library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:96: /fftools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:97: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:98: /doc/examples/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:163: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
Makefile:2: ffbuild/config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:40: /tools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:41: /ffbuild/common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /ffbuild/library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:96: /fftools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:97: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:98: /doc/examples/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:163: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
Makefile:2: ffbuild/config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:40: /tools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:41: /ffbuild/common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /ffbuild/library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:96: /fftools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:97: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:98: /doc/examples/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:163: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
</Users/mac/NDKK>/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android21-clang is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "ffbuild/config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.
Makefile:2: ffbuild/config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:40: /tools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:41: /ffbuild/common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /ffbuild/library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:96: /fftools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:97: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:98: /doc/examples/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:163: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
Makefile:2: ffbuild/config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:40: /tools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:41: /ffbuild/common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /ffbuild/library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:96: /fftools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:97: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:98: /doc/examples/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:163: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
Makefile:2: ffbuild/config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:40: /tools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:41: /ffbuild/common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:94: /ffbuild/library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:96: /fftools/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:97: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:98: /doc/examples/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:163: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
```

Comment: The `No such file or directory` should indicate that you have an error in some path or that somehow you actually do not have those files. Take `NDK_PATH="</Users/mac/NDKK>"`, for example. Is it O.K to have `<` and `>`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use NDK r15c, it has gcc/nm/strip toolchains.

You can refer to below page.

https://blog.csdn.net/King1425/article/details/90410625

I can compile ok with the method described in the page, like below.

[image: compile result on my side]

BR,